# Как написать скрипт, который будет при клике на кнопку ОК, выводить указанное в поле ввода число смайликов на страницу?

Tags: javascript

Надо создать скрипт (лучше с циклом), который будет при клике на кнопку `“ОК”`, выводить указанное в поле ввода число смайликов на страницу.

```css
.smile {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.smile-good:before {
  content: "";
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(41, 128, 185), rgb(109, 213, 250), rgb(255, 255, 255));
}

.wrap {
  width: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  min-height: 120px;
}

.enter-item {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.enter-item input {
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.enter-item button {
  border: 1px solid #2b82bb;
  background: #2b82bb;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <label class="enter-item">
    <input id="input" type="number" placeholder="Введите число">
    <button id="button">OK</button>
    </label>
  <div id="smiles">
    <div class="smile smile-good"></div>
    <div class="smile smile-good"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS Скрипт я очистил чтобы не путать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const id = (bubu) => document.getElementById(bubu);

id('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  let length = +id('input').value;
  let html = new Array( length ).fill('<div class="smile smile-good"></div>').join('');
  // Создает массив длины `length`, заполняет одинаковыми строками, join склеивает всё в 1 строку.
  
  id('smiles').innerHTML = html;
});
```

```css
.smile {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.smile-good:before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" placeholder="Введите число">
<button id="button">OK</button>
<div id="smiles">
  <div class="smile smile-good"></div>
  <div class="smile smile-good"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо всем кто ответил

Answer (score 2):

```js
    button.onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('smiles').innerHTML = "";
        var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
        for (let i=0;i<+value;i++){
            var newElem = document.createElement('div');
            newElem.value = value;
            newElem.className = 'smile smile-good';
            document.getElementById('smiles').appendChild(newElem);
        }
    }
```

```css
        .smile {
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 32px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
        .smile-good:before {
            content: "";
        }
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(41, 128, 185), rgb(109, 213, 250), rgb(255, 255, 255));
        }
        .wrap {
            width: 50%;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 40px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            margin: 10% auto;
            box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
            min-height: 120px;
        }
        .enter-item{
            display: inline-flex;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
        }
        .enter-item input {
            border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
            border-right: 0;
            border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .enter-item button {
            border: 1px solid #2b82bb;
            background: #2b82bb;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <label class="enter-item">
        <input id="input" type="number" placeholder="Введите число">
        <button id="button">OK</button>
    </label>
    <div id="smiles">
        <div class="smile smile-good"></div>
        <div class="smile smile-good"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое